# Learning rust getting compile error when declaring None

Tags: rust, enums

I'm currently reading the official rust-lang book (the one on their website/documentation) and I'm taking notes by copying code and writing comments for everything.  I'm currently on chapter 6, Options enum type.  Based on the book and some Rustlings code I came across while googling the following should be possible [based on the the official book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values)

```
let none: Option<i32> = None;
```

I also have the following notes in comment form next to it :
`If we use None rather than Some, we need to tell Rust what type of Option<T> we have, because the compiler can’t infer the type that the Some variant will hold by looking only at a None value.` And I mean it satisfies the requirement but I keep getting the following error:

```
mismatched types
expected enum `main::Option<i32>`
   found enum `std::option::Option<_>`
```

I did come across this which works:

```
let _equivalent_none = None::<i32>;
```

Can anyone explain why one works but the other doesn't? The official book doesn't even mention the second variant (that doesn't throw an error). Is the newest version different from what's documented in the book?

Comment: This question is a good example of why an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is important. No repro: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df0b69241ce496e3c7b49aa4b4f59e1d

Comment: Man sometimes you just can't catch a break with some people.  At least there were others who were able to help me out and shared insight into something I'm trying to learn.

Comment: "Catch a break"? Nobody is criticizing you for trying to learn. But when you're asking about an error, instead of hoping people guess/infer what you have in front of you just paste it into the question and everyone can see.

Comment: I have a document spanning 750 lines, you want me to post the entire thing?  I know that not a min reproducible example but I wouldnt know what to post.  I have no idea where or what the error is stemming from but it doesn't seem it was hard to infer at all since the correct answers came in literally minutes after posting.  But I digress initially I did see it as a criticism so sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have defined your own enum called `Option` in your program. Thus, there are two different types called `Option`: yours (`main::Option`), and the standard one (`std::option::Option`). The variable `none` has type `main::Option`, but `None` is of type `std::option::Option`.

Obvious solution is to just delete your own enum. If, however, for the sake of experiment you do want to create an instance of your own enum called `Option`, and assign the value of `None` to it, you'd need to qualify `None`:

```
let none: Option<i32> = Option::None;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that defining an `enum Option { None, … }` brings a new `Option` into scope, shadowing the `std::option::Option` imported by `std::prelude` by default. However, `enum Option { None, … }` does not bring a new `None` into scope, so the `std::option::Option::None` imported by prelude is still there.

So, you have two options:

- Use: `let none: Option<i32> = Option::None;`, specifying which none to use explicitly.
- Add a `use crate::Option::*;` below your enum, bringing your own `None` into scope.

Comment: Thank you, very informative, I would have gave you the answer but the other guy came first.

Comment: Oh, that's all right. I just figured `use` would be worth mentioning.